# Symfony2 - data transmission to the view

Tags: symfony, view, controller

I have one question. I want to tranfer object data from controller to the view. What way is better:

1. Transfer a whole object to the view. And then inside view, get
   necessary data from object.
2. Inside controller get a necessary
   data from object and put this to the array. And transfer this array
   to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard and, in my opinion, best way would be the first one.

Passing objects to the view allows you to use the same data structures across the entire application. If you have a `Car` model, for example, you may do something like this in a service:

```
$model = $car->getModel();
```

And in a view you would do something like this:

```
{{ car.model }}
```

Being consistent is a desirable attribute.

Comment: Yep, I know, I'm using this first way. I wanted only the confirmation, that I'm using the right way :P